# Difference between fixed-width and proportional typewriter fonts in listings?

Tags: fonts, listings, verbatim

In the MWE below, I wonder why does the `pcr` (Courier) font align in both escaped and unescaped versions and for whatever column setting of `{listing}` - while the `cmtt` (Computer Modern Teletype) aligns escaped and unescaped only for `fullflexible` columns. The MWE is basically the same code repeated for different fonts (I would have stored it in a macro, but I'd get "Text dropped after begin of listing..." then):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} % \pagecolor
\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

Here entering a sample paragraph with \texttt{some} words entered in
\texttt{typewriter font}, which should also be \texttt{monospaced} - or rather,
\texttt{fixed width}. It can be quite useful for showing \texttt{variables}.

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1a,
columns=fixed,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\fbox{ }cmd one}\linebreak}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1b,
columns=fullflexible,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\fbox{ }cmd one}\linebreak}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}



\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

Here entering a sample paragraph with \texttt{some} words entered in
\texttt{typewriter font}, which should also be \texttt{monospaced} - or rather,
\texttt{fixed width}. It can be quite useful for showing \texttt{variables}.

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex2a,
columns=fixed,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\fbox{ }cmd one}\linebreak}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex2b,
columns=fullflexible,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\fbox{ }cmd one}\linebreak}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

... and the output is this:

[image: test01a.png]

Now this is the weird thing for me: for *fixed* columns, the escaped and unescaped listing text has completely different spacing between characters (compare the `80484c` part in Listing 3) for the font `cmtt`, specifically; this doesn't happen for `pcr`.

So the conclusion I'm making from this, is that apparently `pcr` is a "real" fixed width font, and `cmtt` is "simply" a "typewriter" font, but a proportional one? But for one, `cmtt` doesn't look all that proportional to me - and even if it was, it should align for `columns=fixed`, shouldn't it?

So my questions are:

- is there a (simple) way to determine in Latex if a font is really fixed-width? (e.g. I'd like to type something like `\iffontfixedwidth{cmtt}\typeout{yes}\else\typeout{no}\fi`)
- Could I somehow get `cmtt` to behave the same as `pcr` does in `{listing}` (that is, have the same alignment/spacing between letters, regardless of escaped/unescaped or `columns=` setting)?

Comment: I just experimented with `basewidth=0.51em,` option of `{lstlisting}` - that seems to fix the behavior of `cmtt` -- but then messes up the behavior of `pcr` (in escaped vs unescaped in `columns=fixed`)! So that's not the answer...

Comment: `cmtt` is definitely a fixed-width font.  this can be checked by looking at the width values in the `.tfm` file -- `tftopl cmtt10`.  the width of *every* character is reported as `(CHARWD R 0.524996)`.  so something else is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for that @barbarabeeton - good to know that; cheers!

Answer (score 2):

With `columns=fixed` and `columns=flexible`, the listing is built inserting each character in a box 0.6em wide for `fixed` and 0.45em for `flexible` (the default value can be changed via `basewidth`).

Using these two types is meaningless when the font has fixed width glyphs, like Courier or Computer Modern Typewriter, because for these fonts the interword space is the same as the width of every character, so the columns will line up automatically.

In those cases, `columns=fullflexible` is the best: characters are not inserted in a box and the alignment is automatic.

How to set the `basewidth` to a sensible value for `fixed`? You can exploit the fact that when `basewidth` is computed, the basic font has already been selected, so

```
basewidth=\fontcharwd\font`W,
```

will set this width to the one of the (usually) widest character.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} % \pagecolor
\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Here entering a sample paragraph with \texttt{some} words entered in
\texttt{typewriter font}, which should also be \texttt{monospaced} - or rather,
\texttt{fixed width}. It can be quite useful for showing \texttt{variables}.

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex2a,
columns=fixed,
basewidth=\fontcharwd\font`M,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\_cmd one}\linebreak}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex2b,
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\_cmd one}}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

How to determine if a font is fixed width?

```
\ifdim\fontcharwd\font`i=\fontcharwd\font`W
   <code for fixed width font>
\else
   <code for proportional font>
\fi
```

Of course `\font` refers to the current font.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get somewhere, but not sure how correct it is. Basically, it's all about setting `basewidth=`, but to a correct value, which I've obtained by using `\widthof` from package `calc`. Now, the problem is that we must have an expandable macro for `basewidth=` - and also, I think when `basewidth=` is processed, the `{lstlisting}` environment still doesn't "know" what `\lst@basicstyle` has been set to. This means, that this length has to be calculated before the `{lstlisting}` starts, and the arguments that will be used as `basicstyle=` have to be retyped there. For that, below I use a newcommand.

So, not to paste the whole example, these are the most substantial changes at the start:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}%\widthof
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} % \pagecolor
\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\newlength{\tlen}
% \xdef\etlen{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getMyLen}[1]{%
%   \setlength{\tlen}{\widthof{{\lst@basicstyle W}}}%
  \setlength{\tlen}{\widthof{#1}}%
%   \xdef\etlen{\the\tlen}%
%   \etlen% return
  \the\tlen% return
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

Here entering a sample paragraph with \texttt{some} words entered in
\texttt{typewriter font}, which should also be \texttt{monospaced} - or rather,
\texttt{fixed width}. It can be quite useful for showing \texttt{variables};
\getMyLen{\scriptsize\ttfamily W}.

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1a,
columns=fixed,
basewidth=\tlen,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 !\fbox{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\texttt{80484c4:\fbox{ }cmd one}\linebreak}!
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
...
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

Here entering a sample paragraph with \texttt{some} words entered in
\texttt{typewriter font}, which should also be \texttt{monospaced} - or rather,
\texttt{fixed width}. It can be quite useful for showing \texttt{variables};
\getMyLen{\scriptsize\ttfamily W}.
...
```

... and otherwise add `basewidth=\tlen,` for all `{lstlisting}`; the end result is this:

[image: test01b.png]

... and, so to speak, looks good enough to me in either font. Of course, the question on determining if a font is really fixed-width is still open...